# Grouping arrays by specified key value pair

Tags: php, arrays

Heys guys I have the following array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2017-03-31
            [1] => 7.9950
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2017-06-30
            [1] => 8.3425
        )


    [2] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2017-03-31
            [2] => 6.8250
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2017-06-30
            [2] => 10.7725
        )


    [4] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2017-03-31
            [3] => 6.4950
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2017-06-30
            [3] => 7.3425
        )

)
```

I need to merge all the values that share the same date into one array,  preserving the original keys if possible. They're id's that I'll then json_encode to build a chart.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2017-03-31
            [1] => 7.9950
            [2] => 6.8250
            [3] => 6.4950
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2017-06-30
            [1] => 8.3425
            [2] => 10.7725
            [3] => 7.3425
        )
)
```

Is there a way of achieving this? I've looked for similar questions, searched the php manual for functions like array_merge and alike, but couldn't achieve the desired result. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It all starts with a `foreach`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
$output = array();
foreach($input as $record){
  foreach($record as $key => $value){
    $output[$record['date']][$key] = $value;
  }
}
//make it a regular array
$output = array_values($output);
```

Any duplicate data will appear only once.